# Create new array from existing array with specifc node values

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-arrays

I have following array:

```
[
  {
    fileName: "test.pdf",
    fileUrl: "https://test-url1.com/test.pdf",
    isDeleted: true
  },
  {
    fileName: "test.pdf",
    fileUrl: "https://test-url1.com/test.pdf",
    isDeleted: true
  }
]
```

Now I need to create new array from this array which will contain only fileUrl data.

So that new array will have only fileUrl node and all it's links.

Should I use map OR filter method, or any other suggestion for this.

Thanks

Comment: please add a code snippet instead of code screenshots

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `map` for this.

```
const urlArray = array.map((item: any) => item.fileUrl);

// [ "https://test-url1.com/test.pdf", "https://test-url1.com/test.pdf"]
```

The rule of thumb is if you want to change the structure of the array you use `map`, if you want to get a subset of the array you use `filter`.

Comment: I tried it but I am getting this error : 'item' is of type 'unknown'.ts(18046)